# Updating email addresses of certain "My Contacts" for users of Office 365

Tags: powershell

We have an Office 365 deployment, migrated from another provider. Users have extensive personal address books (labelled as "My Contacts" in Outlook).

A company we work with closely has recently changed its domain name. I need to update the personal contacts of our users so that email addresses for "@foobar.com" now go to "@foobar.co.uk". Getting users to do this themselves is a lot more trouble than it's worth.

There would appear to be lots of guidance on updating Global Address Books using PowerShell, but not on how to update "My Contacts" for the individual users.

Are there any examples, etc or snippets of code for editing the personal contacts of individuals users in PowerShell? Or any example scripts similar in nature?

Comment: I would say that the only way this could be done is with an Outlook COM object. You would have to load that as the user, find contacts that matched the criteria for that, and then replace them. However, I am not sure if there are methods that exist to do that. If it could be done, you would probably have to create a script and run it as the user in their context.

Comment: I created a COM object using this article, but did not get very far on updating contacts:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/01/powertip-list-outlook-contacts-with-powershell/

Comment: I've had quite a bit of success so far in my own testing.  However, I would warn you that your `Contacts` address book *may* be obfuscating the email addresses... they may not look like `abc@xyz.com` and could instead look like `/O=COMPANY/OU=Admin/cn=Recipients/` or similar, when you pull the object properties in.  For any manually entered emails, they work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm the following snippet worked for me, when I setup contacts in my `Contacts` folder, and it successfully rewrote and saved the contact properly.  Note that I also am changing the `DisplayName` field, as (in my location) this doesn't get re-written to reflect the right address in some cases.

**WARNING**:  I've disabled (commented) the actual work in this code for now.  Since it's going to be digging into an unknown (thousands or more?) number of contacts in your `Contacts` folder only (not the Global Address list, with this code).

**The three lines in the middle should be uncommented *only* when you validate you're seeing the expected output via the `Write-Host` commands.**

I'd hate to discover my attempt to help you resulted in rewriting massive quantities of contacts and a headache to recover.

That said, this should definitely give you a head-start, and you can modify as you please/need.

```
$olApp = new-object -comobject outlook.application
$namespace = $olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$Contacts = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(10)

foreach ($Entry in $Contacts.Items)
{

    if ($Entry.Email1Address -like "*foobar*")
    {
        $newAddress = $Entry.Email1Address -replace "foobar.com", "foobar.co.uk"
        $newDisplayName = $Entry.Email1DisplayName -replace "foobar.com", "foobar.co.uk"

        #UNCOMMENT the below lines, once you've confirmed it will work as expected for you
        #$Entry.Email1Address = $newAddress
        #$Entry.Email1DisplayName = $newDisplayName
        #$Entry.Save()

        #COMMENT OUT (or don't) the three below lines, once you've validated that this will work in your environment
        $Entry | Format-Table FullName,Email1Address,Email1DisplayName
        Write-Host ("Would convert " + $Entry.Email1Address + " to... " + $newAddress)
        Write-Host ("Now displayed as " + $Entry.Email1DisplayName + " to... " + $newDisplayName)
    }

}

$olApp.Quit | Out-Null
[GC]::Collect()
```

**Further disclosure**: Consider backing up your contacts list before you run this on the enterprise side.  Also, see my note above about some enterprise systems not displaying email addresses in standard `abc@xyz.com` format.  Hence, why I also provided the `Write-Host` commands, to allow you to see if you have a similar issue.  If so, let us know and I'll try to dig further into how to reference that proper (if it's possible)

You may have to provide it to the users with a batch file, so you don't have to explain how to run it, and also depending on what `ExecutionPolicy` is configured in your enterprise.

Notes on my setup: Windows 7, Office 365 (Outlook 2016 - 16.0.6366.2062 specifically), & PowerShell 5.0, though I feel like the cmdlets and references here are universal.  In case you have issues, that is.

Comment: This works great under my account - sorry to be dense if you've already explained (or it should already be known) - how do I get this to modify the contacts of other people on our domain?

Comment: The code above looks more like it's manipulating Outlook on my local machine and not interacting with Office 365.

Comment: @Metalshark - Q1: As I noted in the answer, you'd need to provide them with a batch file (to account for any domain-specific requirements), or instructions on how to launch the PowerShell script manually.  NOTE: It will only update the folder `My Contacts` as denoted by the `GetDefaultFolder(10)` (10 being the `My Contacts` folder).

Comment: @Metalshark - It is a `COM Object`, created to interact through Outlook, and into the `My Contacts` folder, yes.  What do you mean _"interacting with Office 365?"_  If you're wanting for a method to update *Active Directory*, that would be a different question.  I believe you stated "personal contacts," needed updating - which is what `My Contacts` are.  Can you clarify what you mean when you say you want to interact "_with Office 365?_"

Comment: it's certainly the closest solution and I am appreciative of the obvious effort you have put into answering

Comment: If you need additional modifications, or help in implementing (via a separate script/question), let me know and link to any new questions via these comments, and I'll shift to there to assist as well.  ;)